# Read node value with XMLTextReader

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I try to get the value of a node but it always returns me an empty String. As far as I read I have to access the node first in order to read it but I haven't found an example/the syntax to do it. My XMLNode name is "BuyNowPrice" and is multiple times inside of my XML File.

```
using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlTextReader.Create(@"C:\benatia.xml"))
{
    while (xmlReader.Read())
    {
        if (xmlReader.IsStartElement())
        {
            if (xmlReader.Name == "BuyNowPrice") Console.WriteLine(xmlReader.Name + ": " + xmlReader.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, it would be better practice to use `XmlReader.Create`. `XmlTextReader.Create` is actually the same thing.

Comment: Side note: readers API is probably the hardest one to work with among .Net XML APIs. Unless you looking for 10Mb+ files LINQ-to-XML may be easier to deal with (and definitely way more samples).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to read the content of an element, you need to call `ReadElementContentXxxxx()` method.

```
if (xmlReader.IsStartElement())
 {
 if (xmlReader.Name == "BuyNowPrice") 
      Console.WriteLine(xmlReader.Name + ": " 
              + xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString());
}
```

LinqToXml

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(file);
foreach(var e in xml.Descendants("BuyNowPrice"))
{
 Console.WriteLine(e.Name + " : " + (string)e);
}
```

Comment: You are my hero of the night. I searched so long for this and found this nowhere!

Comment: You should try Linq-to-Xml.

Comment: I will do it when I have to use XML for the next time!